# Google Cloud is unable to pick up my model for deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, model, google-ai-platform

I am creating a model resource for deployment namely ChurnPrediction4

[image]

However in the next line itself when I give the command for the deployment, google cloud is unable to find the same model which i created

[image]

I am not sure what is the issue here and how is unable to found

Answer (score 0):

You have created your model in a region, not globally. In your version creation, if you not mention the region, it's considered as global by default. And your model is not global, but attached to a region.

So add the `--region` in your version create command line